# overlapping htaccess commands?

Tags: php, .htaccess

the problem is the first rewriterule is for my referral values to be allowed with php extension hidden in the link.

*eg. mylink.com/myref*

*status.php* is a different page, however, if i input mylink.com/status it just goes directly to the index. i also want the php of status.php to be hidden as well.
what is the best solution for an overlapping rewrite rules?

*the code :*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?str=$1
RewriteRule ^status$ status.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure after this my example you will get exact idea in detail about that... just copy & try to understand about this...

create one Project Folder, then Create one .htaccess file , user.php, index.php, test.php

then copy below code...
**in .htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^test?$ test.php
RewriteRule ^user?$ user.php
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)$ user.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^game/(1)? http://triviamaker.com [R=301,L]
```

in **user.php** file

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    echo "User Id :".$_GET['id'];
}else{
    echo "<h3>Opps write localhost/user/anynumber</h3>";
}
?>
```

in **index.php** file

```
<?php 
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

in **test.php** file

```
<?php
echo $temp = $_GET['land'];
echo $temp = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    if($temp == "1" || $temp == "land=1"){
        header('Location: https://example.com');
    }else if($temp == "2" || $temp == "land=2"){
        header('Location: https://gmail.com');
    }else if($temp == "3" || $temp == "land=3"){
        header('Location: https://apple.com');
    }else if($temp == "4" || $temp == "land=4"){
        header('Location: user/2');
    }
?>
```

Now Run this files:

1. localhost/*your_project_folder_name*/
2. localhost/_your_project_folder_name/user
3. localhost/_your_project_folder_name/user.php

& also run with parameter like this

1. localhost/_your_project_folder_name/user/1
2. localhost/_your_project_folder_name/user/2
3. localhost/_your_project_folder_name/test?2
4. localhost/_your_project_folder_name/test?3
5. localhost/_your_project_folder_name/game/1

I hope with this example You can understand different different scenarios easily... Thank You